# Obtaining openssl x509 certificate chain sent by server in custom cert_verify_callback

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509, schannel

I am considering overriding the default certificate verification procedure with one that uses the Windows system store (via [SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback.html)). The application is a web client and I need to accept company-wide self-signed certificates added to the system store.

Once I have a (possibly incomplete) chain, I

- create an in-memory WinCrypt store,
- add the server-supplied chain (except the final cert) to it
- build a complete chain using WinCrypt from the temp and system stores
- validate the chain using WinCrypt (passing the servername value from the SSL object)

But [X509_STORE_CTX_get1_chain()](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/X509_STORE_CTX_get_error.html) returns the trusted chain, which is only available after [X509_verify_cert()](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/X509_verify_cert.html) runs.

What I need is X509_STORE_CTX::untrusted (which has just the certs from the handshake) but it's apparently not exported via the API.

I could just pass the final cert to WinCrypt but that would mean downloading the intermediate certs which I want to avoid.

My question is, am I doing something backwards ? Should I let openssl build the chain and do the validation, and then redo it using WinCrypt ? That seems gross. I can add a X509_STORE_CTX_get_untrusted() function and rebuild libeay32.dll but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I konow the **default** verification function is **X509_verify_cert**. This function is called if you don't set your own verification callback (with `SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback`). It is defined in **crypto/x509/x509_vfy.c**. I would suggest you look at the source code of this function to figure out what exactly you should do to convince OpenSSL to collaborate (e.g. return error codes properly).

I hope that helps.

P.S.
It looks like you're right: there are to accessors functions for `X509_STORE_CTX::untrusted`, so it may be OpenSSL's "private" stuff. In the `X509_verify_cert` this variable is simply accessed directly.